# What android:inputType should I use for entering an IP Address and hostname?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-widget

I am building a small Android app where the user will enter an IP address or a hostname into an `EditText` widget.  90% of the time they will be entering an IP address, the rest of the time - a hostname.

So naturally, I want to make it easy for them to enter an IP address, but the ability to switch to alpha numerics for hostname entry is important.

I can't seem to find a good inputType.  The `numberDecimal` initially seemed like a good shot, but it only allows one dot.

Ideally, I'd like to start with a standard keyboard that had the `?123` button pressed.

How do I get there?

Comment: I think only option is EditText type Text. You may need to add validation for IP.

Comment: don't forget, IP addresses are going to start using `a-f` and `:` in 1995…

Answer (score 69):

Try using `android:inputType="number"`, but also set `android:digits="0123456789."`.  Works for me.

Comment: Just read the question again and noticed that the you wanted to be able to enter a hostname as well.  My answer won't work for that, but it will bring up the standard "number" keyboard and allow for multiple dots.

Comment: You _can_ add lower and upper case letters and a hyphen to `digits`, but it is a bit messy. It _will_ work, though.

Comment: Using Android 6.0, `number` didn't show me the dot while `numberDecimal` did.

Comment: For typing "192.168.1.111", either `number` or `numberDecimal` with `digits` didn't work on my Samsung Note 9 (Android 9.0). It just doesn't allow me to type the second dot. I use `Patterns.IP_ADDRESS.matcher("192.168.1.111").matches()` to validate the input in my code.

Answer (score 47):

If you use `inputType="phone"` you gain access to a cut down keyboard containing Numbers and a Period character - this doesn't restrict the input with regards to the amount of Periods you can enter.

Please see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11545229/726954) for validation while being entered.

Comment: Thanks I think this is a good answer. It's so annoying to be brought up with a keyboard for a field that only requires numbers such as an IP Address. Validation is key obviously but you've even provided a link for that! Kudos.

Comment: On Android Marshmallow 23 the period button on the keyboard has been replaced by * and #. Therefore inputType="phone" should not be used for IP address input fields. Use android:inputType="numberDecimal" and android:digits="0123456789." instead as suggested in other questions

Comment: Use `Patterns` work for me, `number` and `numberDecimal` with `digits` didn't work.

Comment: This still allows the user to input `*#(/),` unfortunately.

Answer (score 30):

This works perfectly keyboard with numbers and decimal by adding android:inputType="number|numberDecimal" and android:digits="0123456789."

Example

```
 <EditText
    android:id="@+id/ip_address"
    android:inputType="number|numberDecimal"
    android:digits="0123456789."
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

Comment: perfect solution

Comment: This is the perfect solution. Thank you!

Comment: This doesn't work for me on API Level 27 unfortunately. It only allows one decimal

Comment: works on Pixel 3a XL, android 11 API 30 and Samsung android 7.0 API 24. Thanks!

Answer (score 17):

You can use your own input filter for that

```
final EditText text = new EditText(ServerSettings.this);
InputFilter[] filters = new InputFilter[1];
filters[0] = new InputFilter() {
    @Override
    public CharSequence filter(CharSequence source, int start,
            int end, Spanned dest, int dstart, int dend) {
        if (end > start) {
            String destTxt = dest.toString();
            String resultingTxt = destTxt.substring(0, dstart) +
            source.subSequence(start, end) +
            destTxt.substring(dend);
            if (!resultingTxt.matches ("^\\d{1,3}(\\." +
                    "(\\d{1,3}(\\.(\\d{1,3}(\\.(\\d{1,3})?)?)?)?)?)?")) { 
                return "";
            } else {
                String[] splits = resultingTxt.split("\\.");
                for (int i=0; i<splits.length; i++) {
                    if (Integer.valueOf(splits[i]) > 255) {
                        return "";
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    return null;
    }
};
text.setFilters(filters);
```

Comment: Thanks for this.  This answer was exactly what I needed.

Comment: Not working with spannables, since the whole input gets replaced with an empty string in some cases. See Łukasz Sromeks answer at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3349121/how-do-i-use-inputfilter-to-limit-characters-in-an-edittext-in-android

Answer (score 6):

use this :

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/txtIP"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:digits="0123456789."
 />
```

Answer (score 5):

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/ip_address"
    android:inputType="number|numberDecimal"
    android:digits="0123456789."
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

worked for me

Comment: Using `number|numberDecimal` only allows one dot.

Comment: add `android:digits="0123456789."` too

Comment: My mistake. Using inputType + digits works fine on Android, but not on FireOS (Amazon Android fork) which has a custom dialog implementation.

Answer (score 1):

I think your only option is..

```
EditText android:inputType="text" ... />
```

You could possible check the Text for 3 dots a IP address contains

Comment: User wants same text box need to handle host name and IP, number may constrian it to only number. Even IP he can't enter because of DOTS.

Comment: "number" won't let you switch to letters and won't let u enter a dot.

Comment: I think your only option is Text. You can then check the IP address for consistency to make sure the decimals are in place.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to use [TextWatcher](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher.html) for validation, register it with [TextView.addTextChangedListener()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#addTextChangedListener%28android.text.TextWatcher%29) method and use [Pattern.DOMAIN_NAME](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Patterns.html#DOMAIN_NAME) and [Pattern.IP_ADDRESS](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Patterns.html#IP_ADDRESS) (Android 2.2+).

See:
[Android: How can I validate EditText input?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2763022/android-how-can-i-validate-edittext-input)
[Validating IP in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3698034/validating-ip-in-android)

Comment: This is validation - I got that part.  I am only concerned right now with making it easy on the user and not having the user tap extra keys.

Answer (score 1):

You can extend the DigitsKeyListener ([source](http://www.java2s.com/Open-Source/Android/android-core/platform-frameworks-base/android/text/method/DigitsKeyListener.java.htm)) and change the filter() function (validation that will check either ip pattern or a string hostname) and getInputType() to `return InputType.TYPE_CLASS_PHONE;`

Answer (score 1):

Maybe if you use 2 radiobutton, one shows an edittext for host, the other one shows 4 numeric edittext for IP, then, once the user submit data you concat all 4 edittext values with dots between them, something like this, edittext1.getText() + "." + edittext2.getText() + "." edittext3.getText() + "." edittext4.getText() so you can obtain a validated IP address like that but obviously it will imply more work.

Comment: Good golly I hate when apps try to make entering an IP address "easier". Guess what, if I know what an IP address is, I can probably find the "." button.

Comment: @gladed Well, the idea was in order to facilitate IP validation and make user input easier

Comment: You can easily validate a string against Patterns.IP_ADDRESS. For the user, tapping back and forth between different fields in an IP address is never easier. Have you ever seen a phone dialer with separate area-code/3-digit-prefix/4-digit-suffix fields? Or an email widget with different fields for name/domain? Please just don't.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the code that allows you to display a soft keyboard with only numbers and a dot (but allows you to enter multiple dots).

```
etIpAddress.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);
etIpAddress.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_DECIMAL);
etIpAddress.setKeyListener(DigitsKeyListener.getInstance(false,false));
etIpAddress.setKeyListener(DigitsKeyListener.getInstance("0123456789."));
```

Answer (score 0):

SKTs answer is working pretty well until the [InputFilter](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/InputFilter) passes [Spannables](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Spannable). Spannables are tricky to handle which is described for example ins answers of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3349121/how-do-i-use-inputfilter-to-limit-characters-in-an-edittext-in-android). In this case, returning `""` for invalid input will replace the whole text by an empty string. I've adapted the solution also to handle this case. Here is the code, differing the types, in Kotlin:

```
val ipAddressFilters = arrayOf(InputFilter { source, start, end, dest, dstart, dend ->
    if (end > start) {
        val toCheck = if (source is Spannable) {
            source.toString()
        } else {
            val destString = dest.toString()
            destString.substring(0, dstart) + source.subSequence(start, end) + destString.substring(dend)
        }
        if (!toCheck.matches("^\\d{1,3}(\\.(\\d{1,3}(\\.(\\d{1,3}(\\.(\\d{1,3})?)?)?)?)?)?".toRegex())) {
            return@InputFilter if (source is Spannable) { dest } else { "" }
        } else {
            val splits = toCheck.split("\\.".toRegex()).toTypedArray()
            for (i in splits.indices) {
                if (splits[i] != "" && Integer.valueOf(splits[i]) > 255) {
                    return@InputFilter if (source is Spannable) { dest } else { "" }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    null
})
```

Answer (score -1):

Try using `android:inputType="textUri"`. It works especially well when you want hostname or IP address.