# dots not visible in edittext with number inputType only in landscape orientation

Tags: android, android-edittext, landscape

I'm trying to do an edittext for IP input, so input chars are numbers and dots:

```
android:inputType="number"
android:digits="0123456789."
```

this works great but when change to landscape view dots are invisible. Keyboard is working well, if i touch dot button a dot is added, when come back to normal view all dots are visible. How can i get dots visible in landscape view?
Thanks

Comment: Same resource file for both layouts?

Comment: Not, but EditText properties are the same.

Comment: Can be related to the language of the device?

Comment: Same issue on android 4.0, russian locale.Looks like a platform bug.

Answer (score 0):

Change android:inputType="number"
to  android:inputType="phone"

https://stackoverflow.com/a/11543734/1802587