# Validating IP never succeeds

Tags: java, android, validation, ip, matcher

The user enters an IP address in a EditTextPreference and I try to validate the IP with this code:

```
private EditTextPreference ipPref;
private Matcher matcher;
private SharedPreferences settings;
private final Pattern IP_ADDRESS
    = Pattern.compile(
    "((25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[0-1][0-9]{2}|[1-9][0-9]|[1-9])\\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4]"
    + "[0-9]|[0-1][0-9]{2}|[1-9][0-9]|[1-9]|0)\\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[0-1]"
    + "[0-9]{2}|[1-9][0-9]|[1-9]|0)\\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[0-1][0-9]{2}"
    + "|[1-9][0-9]|[0-9]))");

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.settings);

    //PREF_IP is the android:key of the EditTextPreference
    ipPref = (EditTextPreference) getPreferenceManager().findPreference("PREF_IP"); 
    settings = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    matcher = IP_ADDRESS.matcher(settings.getString("PREF_IP", "0.0.0.0"));

ipPref.setOnPreferenceChangeListener(new Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener() {            
        public boolean onPreferenceChange(Preference preference, Object newValue) {

            try 
            {
                if(matcher.matches()){
                    Log.d("settings", "matches!");
                    return true;
                }else{
                    Log.d("settings", "doesn't match!");
                    return false;
                }
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }); 
}
```

If I enter a valid IP address the code never sees it as valid and the log says "doesn't match!". What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You should create your matcher in the method `onPreferenceChange()` instead of creating it upfront.

Comment: @GuillaumePolet that doesn't change anything.

Comment: Yes it changes everything. But im not sure your regexp is correct

Comment: @GuillaumePolet : I tried it and the behaviour doesn't change... that was I meant. The regex should be ok, I got it from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3698034/validating-ip-in-android

Comment: Don't know the exact internals of Android, but if you use someting like this in the onPreferenceChange() method,it should work: `IP_ADDRESS.matcher(newValue.toString()).matches()`

Comment: That's correct! I was stupid to not take care of the Object newValue! Add your answer if you want me to accept it. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your test in the `onPreferenceChange()` method, to:

```
 IP_ADDRESS.matcher(newValue.toString()).matches()
```